Using two Pi 5s together to handle four cameras
I am not sure how to do this, but what I wanted to do is:

Using two Raspberry Pi 5 with each connecting two cameras.
The four cameras should be able to simultaneously recording 4k or HD video at at least 30fps.
No preview or any further processing is required when video is being recorded.
The video from different cameras should be synchronized which means we know which frame and which are acquired at the time of recording.
I would like to keep the whole system compact (about a size of an American football perhaps).

In the end, each Pi 5 should have video from two cameras that attached to it, and the video files from each both Pi 5s will be combined together.
Since it is simply a video buffer saving project, I figure 2 Pi 5s should be able to handle this? I'd imagine these two Pis should be synced by some mechanism, and if one starts to record, the other should start at the same time.
I am not sure how to get it done, one Pi as master, the other as slave, or should they communicate via Ethernet? There are some Pi cluster projects been done but they seem overkill. Any pointer is highly appreciated. I am open to all solutions. Thank you!

Why use 2 RPis? Why not get 4 USB cameras and use 1 RPi? And, likely, many will ask "how closely synchronized"? It may be your (missing key) requirement is so difficult that an OS (LInux/Windows/Unix) is not a good solution.

@st2000 I am open to all solutions. Is there a sample project I can refer to? How does video from 4 cameras feed into one Pi? I suppose there is only one USB port on each one Pi? I'd like to know what limit such a system can achieve. Thank you so much.

@JaromandaX I am sorry I have never seen a Koala in my life. I figure American football is reasonably more commonly seen.

"... I am open to all solutions"... Again, have no idea what "closely synchronized" means from your perspective. And most RPis have 4 USB ports. But even the most casual user understands USB hubs can be used to expand any computer's USB capabilities. It is starting to sound like there are many unknowns for this project. None of the dozens of stackexchange web sites are setup for discussions. Only for 1 concise question and well thought out answers per post.

@st2000 Can those four USB ports connect to different type of cameras? Is the band width a problem? Say saving 4 cameras with each having recording at HD/4K at 60fps/30fps? Acquisition should be simultaneous. Thank you!!

American football is not a unit of measure

are you able to synchronize two cameras on one RPi?

@jsotola I have not tried but Pi 5 has two ports, and I would expect it a synchronized acquisition.

@jsotola - neither is the average size of a male koala, apparently

@NickXTsui I would expect it to be not synchronized until tested otherwise

Since you are not saying how well synchronized the video has to be (i.e. frames no further apart than, say, 100ms) or how you are going to manage to simultaneously play them back synchronously (did you even think about playing them back?) ... well, then, the answers are open to all kinds of interpretation. So here's one: Forget about building anything with a Raspberry Pi. Just buy a high resolution multiple security camera system. All the videos will have time stamp overlays. How you  play them back synchronously is up to you.
